# Wordpress shortcodes and insert tags p and br

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I have problem using wordpress in the shortcodes, I use return to show values but the problem continues, the shortcode shows ok, but the are `<p>` and `<br`> tags in it.

**The content of thext into my template :**

```
<div class="content">

[shortcode_poll="1"]

</div>
```

I tried all, and the problem persists. I used one plugin to remove this lines but it does not work.

I also tried

```
 remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

If you know how fix this please tell me how ?

Comment: Shortcodes should not be used in your template, but they should be used in the editor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the priority of wpautop fixes this (or it did for me at least). Add this to functions.php in your theme.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 12 );
```